# CSS animation on focus reset

Tags: html, css, animation

I am working on a material style animation for my buttons. Was trying to avoid any JS, so came to the following styles:

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/zNJyqg

// Animations

```
.btn {
    position: relative;

    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; bottom: 0; left: -10%; right: -10%;
        border-top-left-radius: 2% 50%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2% 50%;
        border-top-right-radius: 2% 50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2% 50%;
        background-color: fade(black,5%);
        transform: scale(0,1);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    &:focus {

        &:after {
            animation: click-animation .6s linear;
            animation-fill-mode: backwards;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes click-animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0,1);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(.5,1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}
```

It works pretty much as expected (at least on Chrome). The problem is if you click the button multiple times, the animation will only fire once. This happens because the button is already "focused", so it won't repeat the animation. Clicking anywhere outside the button, then clicking on the button again fixes the issue. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: For an animation to be restarted, it must first be removed from the element and attached again. This is needed because the UA keeps track of the iteration count. So, either removing the `focus` via JS or nullifying the animation property's value via JS (by listening to the animationend event) is most probably needed. It maybe possible that somebody could rewrite the whole thing in a different way and achieve what you want but with the current approach, I don't think it is possible without using JS.

Comment: Thanks @Harry. Yea, I've seen those examples with hidden radio buttons, but those look even more ugly.

Comment: @Harry &:focus:not(:active) { ... } made it work!

Comment: Clever hack I'd say (no, I am not degrading the answer in any way). The `:not(:active)` would mean that when you click a second time, the anchor is `:active` and so the UA is actually flushing out the animation (because it is no longer applicable) and then immediately the `:not(:active)` gets applied (as `:active` is a very short span event). Very clever!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the "&:focus" by a "&:not(:active)" and hide your button during page loading to deal with the first animation. More explanation on this here: https://www.screenfeed.fr/blog/css3-animation-on-click-without-js-0828/

Comment: wow, this is something I can work with. Never thought of this approach.

Comment: Ha! &:focus:not(:active) { ... } made this work as expected without hiding the button on page load!

Comment: @Deka87 This solution is clearly counterintuitive, but efficient, furthmore with your addition :).

Answer (score 1):

Tyrian's suggestion to use `&:focus:not(:active)` is a nice suggestion. However if you want an animation on mouse down, instead of mouse up, the following not totally ideal method might be helpful.

The problem with my method is that there is a 30 ms timeout before the animation fires. Removing `setTimeout` causes all browsers that I tested to play the animation only once. On Firefox, changing the 30 ms timeout to 10 ms appears to lead to a race condition causing the animation to not always play. On slower browsers, the delay may need to be longer.

```
<script>
function flashButton (elem) {

    "use strict";

    elem.classList.remove("animate");
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.classList.add("animate");
    }, 30);
}
</script>

<style>
button.animate {
    animation-name: button-animation;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
}
@keyframes button-animation {  
    from { background: #555555; }
    to   { background: #9F9F9F; }
}
</style>

<button onfocus="flashButton(this)" onmousedown="flashButton(this)">X</button>
```

The code works by removing the animation class, then re-adding it right away so that the animation occurs almost immediately.

Adding the class right after clicking, then removing it with a delay wouldn't work very well if the clicks are more frequent than the duration of the animation.